# How do I delete Drafts and Old Inactive Messages from SMS/MobileConnect?

Tags: delete, mobileconnect, sms

We had a bunch of SMS messages that were never launched and I wanted to clean up the space. Is there a way to delete Drafts from MobileConnect without having to make them active? 
On the same hand, is it possible to delete inactive SMS messaging that are older then a certain date?